# Android : Cannot insert values to database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to insert into my phpMyAdmin database the path of a video and its thumbnail both as Strings. The problem is that these values are not stored in my database and I keep getting "success":"0","message":"Required field(s) is missing". Do you have any ideas why this happens?

Here is the code i use

**Android:**

```
public class UploadActivity extends Activity {
        // LogCat tag
        private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
        InputStream is =null;
        private ProgressBar progressBar;
        private String filePath = null;
        public String serverPath;
        private TextView txtPercentage;
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        private VideoView vidPreview;
        private Button btnUpload;
        long totalSize = 0;
        String thumb2string;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
            txtPercentage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPercentage);
            btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

            vidPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);
            // Receiving the data from previous activity
            Intent i = getIntent();

            // video path that is captured in previous activity
            filePath = i.getStringExtra("filePath");
            serverPath = i.getStringExtra("serverPath");


            if (filePath != null) {
                // Displaying video on the screen
                previewMedia();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry, file path is missing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // uploading the file to server
                    new UploadFileToServer().execute();
                }
            });

        }

        /**
         * Displaying captured image/video on the screen
         * */
        private void previewMedia() {


                vidPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vidPreview.setVideoPath(filePath);

                // start playing
                vidPreview.start();

        }

        /**
         * Uploading the file to server
         * */
        public class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // setting progress bar to zero
                progressBar.setProgress(0);
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                // Making progress bar visible
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // updating progress bar value
                progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

                // updating percentage value
                txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return uploadFile();
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public String uploadFile() {
                String responseString = null;

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

                try {

                    AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                            new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void transferred(long num) {
                                    publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                                }
                            });
                    File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

                    // Adding file data to http body
                    entity.addPart("video", new FileBody(sourceFile));
                    totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
                    httppost.setEntity(entity);

                    // Making server call
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

                    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    if (statusCode == 200) {
                        // Server response
                        Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath,
                                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        thumb.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                        byte[] thumbnailBitmapBytes = stream.toByteArray();
                        thumb2string = new String(thumbnailBitmapBytes);
                        /*db=openOrCreateDatabase("TwentyThree", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

                        SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO videos (path, thumbnail) values (?, ?)");
                        stmt.bindString(1, serverPath);
                        stmt.bindBlob(2, thumbnailBitmapBytes);
                        stmt.executeInsert();*/
                        insertInto();

                        responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                    } else {
                        responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                                + statusCode;
                    }

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    responseString = e.toString();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    responseString = e.toString();
                }

                return responseString;

            }

            private void insertInto() throws IOException {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Path", "serverPath"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Thumbnail", "thumb2string"));

                try{
                   HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                   HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.96:80/DBscripts/insertdb.php");
                   httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                   is = entity.getContent();
                }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
                    Log.e("ClientProtocol", "Log_tag");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);

                // showing the server response in an alert dialog
                showAlert(result);

                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }

        }

        /**
         * Method to show alert dialog
         * */
        private void showAlert(String message) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Response from Servers")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            UploadActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }

    }
```

**PHP script :**

```php
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','pswd');
mysqli_select_db($con,"twentythree");

if (isset($_POST['Path']) && isset($_POST['Thumbnail'])) {
$path =$_POST['Path'];
$thumb =$_POST['Thumbnail'];

$query = "INSERT INTO videos(Path, Thumbnail) VALUES('".$path."','".$thumb."')";
// mysql inserting a new row
mysqli_query($con,$query);


}else{
// required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);

}
?>
```

Comment: Does your database user have all the necessary permissions ? What does var_dump($_POST) at the top of your PHP script give you? It is possible that this is not at all a database issue.

Comment: @Maximus2012 How can I check this ? I mean the permissions

Comment: At this point don't worry about that part. It looks like the control is not even going to  that part of the code that inserts into the database. Try the var_dump thing to see if the values are even getting passed to your php script.

Comment: @Maximus2012 var_dump($_POST) returns this : array(0) {}

Comment: That means the POST values are not getting passed to your PHP script. You might want to review the Android code that sends the request to the PHP script. That might be causing the issue.

Comment: Also make sure that serverPath and thumb2string values are actually set before you send the request to php code. You can try testing the code with some hard-coded values for these parameters and see if that works.

Comment: @Maximus2012 ok I ll give it a shot

Comment: @Maximus2012 hardcoded values suggestion did not work

Comment: @SoCo Do you have the Android code in a background thread, such as a `AsyncTask`?  It would be a problem if this code is running on the main thread.

Comment: @Daniel Nugent I dont use AsyncTask . I posted my full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution. The problem was at the way I used to encode the byte array to string. So instead of using `thumb2string = new String(thumbnailBitmapBytes);` I used Base64 encoding : `thumb2string = Base64.encodeToString(thumbnailBitmapBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);`